# How to cleanse SQL input in raw django

Tags: mysql, sql, django, django-models, sql-injection

I have the following query that is run when someone performs a search:

```
search = request.GET.get('search', '')
titles = Title.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM title WHERE MATCH(new_composite_title)
         AGAINST ('" + search + "') LIMIT 10")
```

How would I clean the above input to prevent against SQL injection?

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust user input. It is fraught with sql injection. Use [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) QuerySet modifier with `params` argument. Look [here](http://www.mercurytide.co.uk/news/article/django-full-text-search/) for MySQL's full text search example.